# Variant of the rope burning logic puzzle

Tags: puzzle

Given a rope which will burn at a varying rate and can be lit multiple times anywhere along its length. Re-lighting is not possible.

The question is: is it possible to measure a quarter of an hour given only a single rope?

(the reason for this formulation is that I'm trying to map this into parallel searching of random trees [hence the lack of relighting], and I was wondering if this had already been solved for n>2, i.e. trying to measure a quarter/eighth/sixteenth/...)

Comment: Usually in these problems you have more than one rope.

Comment: @lulu The first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303105/rope-burning-question-which-is-not-possible) gives an approach with one rope.

Comment: @almagest  Thanks!  I guess the point is that the rules are not clear, and are certainly not universal.  [sometimes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/170/burning-ropes-as-timers-how-many-time-intervals-can-be-measured) it is specified that you can only light a rope at its ends, for instance.

Comment: @almagest almost, I was hoping it was possible to do without relighting... I'll update the question to be more clear.

Comment: @Cjen1 Given that the rope does not burn uniformly, I don't see how you could hope to do it without relighting. To get 1/4 of the time you need four flames moving along the rope at all times. That inevitably involves a chance of relighting being required.

Comment: @almagest that was unfortunately what I was thinking the answer was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the "no re-lighting" restriction means this:

> At time $0$, you are allowed to set fire to any finite number of positions, each position $\in [0,1]$ along the rope, simultaneously.  However you are not allowed to set more fires at any time $t > 0$.

Then measuring $15$ minutes is impossible.  Consider any set of positions $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n$.  Then:

- If $x_1 = 0$, construct a rope that burns instantly beyond $x_2$, and we are now reduced to the remaining rope burning at both ends, measuring $30$ minutes.
- if $x_1 > 0$, construct a rope that burns instantly beyond $x_1$, and we are now reduced to the remaining rope burning at one end, measuring $60$ minutes.

In other words, for any set of positions determined at time $0$, there exists a rope for which the set of positions measures either $30$ or $60$ minutes, but not $15$ minutes.  Since you don't know what rope you're getting to begin with, this proves no algorithm will work for all ropes.